# SharePoint Failed to load viewstate.The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the cntrl tree that was used to

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

Although, there are many similar question related to Asp.net: Failed to load viewstate. However, in my case with in the context of SharePoint (Server side) I am facing:

> Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.

Scenario is sometime at:

- login (using update panel)
- submitting data related to queries (update panel)
- upload file (update panel)
- logging out (no update panel)
- Cascading dropdownlist (within update panel)

Problem is sometime it is through this exception & sometime it works. There is no child control embedding or hiding etc. Can't able to replicate on my local dev environment or internal QA server. However at client side Staging environment we are having this issue

Already remove viewstate or update enableviewstate="off"

Answer (score 0):

And solution to this problem is session stickiness on load balancer!!!! We assume that applications on load balancer server should have this enable by default. But that was not the case.
Hope it might help someone in near future!!!